# Почему присваивается мусор?

Tags: c++, ассемблер

здравствуйте, начинаю въезжать в ассемблер, придумываю себе простой код для примера:

```
auto hi() {
    int i = 2;
    int arr[]={1,1,1,1,1};
    int d = arr[-1];
}
```

я считал, что d должно присвоиться значение 2... ну мол i и arr лежат рядом последовательно, выравнивания нету в стеке. однако там мусор, ассемблерный выхлоп помог понять что 2 не должно было присвоиться:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
movl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)
movl   $0x1,-0x20(%rbp)
movl   $0x1,-0x1c(%rbp)
movl   $0x1,-0x18(%rbp)
movl   $0x1,-0x14(%rbp)
movl   $0x1,-0x10(%rbp)
mov    -0x24(%rbp),%eax
mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
nop
pop    %rbp
retq
```

но возникла пару других вопросов: почему d лежит именно в смещении -0x8 относительно rbp? переменная i лежит в -0x4 ( это понятно т.к. самая первая переменная в стеке ), почему массив начинается не следом, с -0x8, а с -0x20 и идет до -0x10? я думал, что i будет лежать в -0x4, далее массив начиная с -0x8 и так далее, а в переменную d запишется как раз то, что было до -0x8 т.е. -0x4

Comment: но вы же отрицательный индекс указываете, вот он и берет то, что перед массивом.

Comment: ну так перед массивом же i лежит

Comment: Почему? Компилятор мог поместить `i` в регистр.

Comment: в ассемблерном выхлопе же i в стеке лежит

Comment: @xperious: Что такое "лежит перед массивом"? В языке С такого понятия нет и в помине и никогда не было.

Comment: ну стек же не абстрактная вещь: сначала одна переменная кладется, затем другая, за ней третья... ну логично, что первая перед второй будет)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Во-первых, даже если переменная `i` предшествует массиву `arr` в памяти, все равно никто вам не гарантирует, что переменная `i` будет расположена в памяти *вплотную* с массивом `arr`.

Во-вторых, реализация имеет полную свободу выбора порядка расположения локальных переменных в кадре стека функции. Реализация запросто может расположить их в порядке объявления, но в направлении роста стека, которое в подавляющем большинстве платформ - сверху-вниз, т.е. в порядке *убывания* адресов. То есть в натуральном порядке возрастания адресов, переменная `i` на самом деле будет располагаться *после* массива `arr`, а не перед ним. Если компилятор сохранил ваш порядок, то через `arr[-1]` вы скорее попадете в `d`, а не в `i`. Однако уже ваш пример показывает, что порядок сохранен не был.

В-третьих, понятное дело, что ничего подобного в языке С сделать нельзя в принципе. Никто вам в С не разрешал не просто доступаться к `arr[-1]`, а даже вычислять положение `arr[-1]` в памяти. Не говоря о ваших совершенно не обоснованных ожиданиях на тему порядка расположения переменных в памяти.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, надо будет его переварить еще...
и по поводу роста адресации стека разбираться походу надо